# Set() on a very long list and creating an even longer matrix

Tags: python, set

I'm trying to get the set() of all words in a very long database of books (around 60,000 books) and to store in a matrix the 'vocabularies' of each book (the paths of books are in "files"):

```
for f in files:
    book = open(f, 'r')
    vocabulary = []

    for lines in book.readlines():
        words = string.split(lines)
        vocabulary += set(words)
    matrix.extend([vocabulary])
    V += set(vocabulary)
```

OK, I solved the (memory) problem by creating a file to store everything, but now I get another memory error when trying to create a matrix with:

entries = numpy.zeros((len(V),a))

I tried to solve this by:

```
entries = numpy.memmap('matrice.mymemmap', shape=(len(V),a))
```

but the terminal says:

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/memmap.py", line 193, in **new**
    fid = open(filename, (mode == 'c' and 'r' or mode)+'b')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'matrice.mymemmap'

Can you help me solve this too?

Comment: You should close the file after the open operation is finished.

Comment: do you set V earlier in the code? It may take some time to get through every line in a book and then choke on V += if you haven't declared V yet

Comment: There is a limit on the number of open files a process is allowed. The limit depends on your OS and its settings. I believe the limit in CPython is 512.

Comment: Now you are adding to `vocabulary` unique words from 1 line. I think what you need is add all words to `vocabulary` then make `vocabulary = list(set(vocabulary))` if you want a list all words (unique) from one file.

Comment: You can check the file limit on Unix/Linux with the `ulimit -n` command. But most likely you should be closing file pointers when you are done with them.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't show that too, but I declare V before the code I posted and I close book after that...

Answer (score 2):

```
V = set()

for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as book:
        for lines in book.readlines():
            words = lines.split(" ")
            V.update(words)
```

Here you first create an empty set. Then for each file you iterate through the lines in the file and split each line by the spaces. This gives you a list of words on the line. Then you update the set by the list of words, i.e. only unique words remain in the set.

So, you will end up with `V` which contains all the words in your library.

Of course, you might want to clean some upper/lower cases and punctuation in `words` before updating the set and remove empty words (`""`). That should happen before the `V.update()` statement. Otherwise you end up with both, e.g., `It` and `it`, `fortunately,` and `fortunately`, etc.

Please note the `with` statement with file operation. This ensures that whatever happens, the file will be closed before you leave the with-block.

If you want to do this book-by-book, then:

```
vocabularies = []

for f in files:
    V = set()
    with open(f, 'r') as book:
        for lines in book.readlines():
            words = lines.split(" ")
            V.update(words)
    vocabularies.append(V)
```

Also, instead of `for lines in book.readlines():` you may use just `for lines in book:`.

Comment: I think OP also wants to store the vocabulary of each book. Also I would avoid making the assumption that the only delimiter between words is " ". Although that is its own problem.

Comment: @PaulSeeb: You may be right, now also that version is available.

Comment: I've already removed all punctuation and upper cases, so that's not a problem (and that's why I split only by " ")
I've tried your code, but the awful "Killed" goes on appearing on my terminal :'(

Comment: @Silvia: Now, this is interesting, because that solution should not consume much resources (except for a lot of time). It is also very un-Pythonic for a process to just die, usually Python programs throw an exception when they crash. Please, add some tracking to the code so that we now where it crashes. Is it during the first book or during the 7234th book? Maybe you might add a `print f` statement immediately after the `V=set()` line.

Comment: I did what you suggested and the program has crashed during the 3200th book...any idea? I'm desperate! Thank you anyway.....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code does what you think it does:

```
for f in files:
    book = open(f, 'r')
    vocabulary = []
```

You've created an empty list called `vocabulary`

```
    for lines in book.readlines():
        words = string.split(lines)
        vocabulary += set(words)
```

For each line in the file, you're creating a set of the words in that line. But then you add it to `vocabulary`, which is a list. This just puts the elements on the end of the list. If a word appears on multiple lines, it will appear in `vocabulary` once for every line. This could make `vocabulary` very large.

```
    matrix.extend([vocabulary])
```

From this, I would assume that matrix is also a list. This will give you one entry in matrix for each book, and that entry will be a huge list as described above.

```
    V += set(vocabulary)
```

Is V a list or a set? This copies vocabulary, which is already a set, into another set. Then it takes all the elements of that copied set and adds them to V.

---

First of all, I think you probably intend for vocabulary to be a set. To create an empty set, use `vocabulary = set()`. To add one item to a set, use `vocabulary.add(word)` and to add a collection use `vocabulary.update(words)`. It looks like you mean to do the same with V. That should reduce your memory requirements a lot. That alone might be enough to fix your problem.

If that's not enough to make it work, consider whether you need all of `matrix` in memory at once. You could write it to a file instead of accumulating it in memory.

You'll probably accumulate lots of extra words due to punctuation and capitalization. Your sets would be smaller if you didn't count `'clearly', 'Clearly', 'Clearly.', 'clearly.', 'clearly,'...` as being distinct.

As others have noted, you should use a `with` statement to make sure your file is closed. However, I doubt this is causing your problem. While it's not guaranteed by all Pythons, in this case the file is probably getting closed automatically quite promptly.

Comment: I did what you suggested, that's more or less what I'd already been told, but the program crashes anyway. And I had already removed all punctuation and capitalization...don't know what to do :(

Comment: What are you going to do with `matrix` when you're done? My inclination would be to process each book one at a time and write out a vocabulary file for each separately. See if that works and gives correct results. Then try to produce V by iterating over them and see if that works. Only then try to tackle cramming all of matrix into memory. I suspect that matrix may just be too huge to store in memory if you have thousands of books. The benefit of writing the files separately is that you can see how big they are and inspect them manually.

Comment: I need matrix to iterate over all vocabularies and check if certain words appear into them; I've done what you suggested. writing everything on file, but now I get a memory error with the matrix numpy.zeros((len(V),a)) - as edited
Can you help me?

Comment: I'm happy to try to give you a hand, but I think this isn't the best forum. You could ask a new question, linking back to this one, explaining in more detail what you're trying to do and what you've done. Feel free to email me (clockworksaint@gmail.com), either with the URI of your new question or just for advice. I'll try to give you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can't add values to a list using `+=`. instead, use

```
vocabulary.append(set(words))
```

EDIT: was wrong.

Comment: Sure you can! `A = range(3); A += [9]`

Comment: @usualme well I'll be. I learned the .append() when I first was starting out along with the "python zen" mantra, and just kind of assumed!

Edited. sorry, all!